# Android file handling code working in marshmallow but not in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-file

The same code as mentioned below works in Marshmallow but doesn't work in Kitkat.

The code is taking the data from EditText and saving it in Internal Storage. 
There are 2 buttons `save` and `load` save `onClick - save`, load `onClick - load` .Unable to find the problem. Please help

```
EditText editText;
    Button save, load;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_test);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSAVE);
        load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLOAD);
    }

    public void save(View v) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        File file = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            file = getFilesDir();
            Log.e("AUG", file.toString());
            fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("mytext.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(fileOutputStream!=null){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file+"/mytext.txt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void load(View v){
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("mytext.txt");
            int read = -1;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read=fileInputStream.read())!=-1){
                stringBuffer.append((char)read);
            }
            Log.e("AUG LOAD DATA", stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "but doesn't work in Kitkat" means. Also, **always log exceptions**, as you are not doing that here.

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: What fails, the write or the load? BTW, reading a single character at a time from stream, is very inefficient.